# Difference between two Foreign key model fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model named 'CarAdd', and two other models are connected with a foreign key to this CarAdd model that are ShippingDetails, MaintenanceDetails. and each foreign key model has an item and price field." foreign key have more than 2 items under one id"

I need to find the profit amount of each car

```
profit = sold_amount - (purchased amount + total shipping cost + total maintenance cost)

class CarAdd(models.Model):

    # Car Details
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    purchased_amount = models.DecimalField()
     # there 3 choices in STATUS shipped, maintenance, sold
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=STATUS)

    sold_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=1)

    profit_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=1)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status == 'sold':
            sum_invested = self.purchased_amount + ShippingDetails.price + MaintenanceDetails.price
            profit = self.sold_amount - sum_invested
            self.profit_amount = profit
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class ShippingDetails(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(CarAdd, related_name='shipping_details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=1,)

class MaintenanceDetails(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(CarAdd, related_name='maintenance_details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=1)
```

how do I calculate the profit amount if status is 'sold' and save to profit_amount field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate on the related models:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
sum_invested = self.purchased_amount 
               + self.shipping_details.aggregate(total_price=Coalesce(Sum('price'), 0))['total_price'] 
               + self.maintenance_details.aggregate(total_price=Coalesce(Sum('price'), 0))['total_price']
```

Comment: in save
    'price__sum'] + self.maintenance_details.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'

Comment: ah, your `CarAdd` doesn't always have associated shipping details or maintenance details, in which case Sum return None instead of a value.

Comment: It's Working, Thank you